# How to display events in chronological order?

Tags: views

I am new in Drupal and I want to display events in chronological order by start date of the event.

My current setup is that the latest added event is showing.

Here is a screenprint of the View I created so far:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: in sort criteria "SORT CRITERIA" of view set Content: Post date to asc will display date result on date sort criteria.

Comment: How will I set this can you give the example as i told i am new in drupal,it will be really helpful to me

Comment: at left bottom corner of event views you may find "SORT CRITERIA" set Content: Post date to asc

Comment: yes i have done it  it is showing the event which is added latest but i want the event should be short by the most recent date

Comment: then set "desc" in date field

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of Views Setting UI section?

Comment: screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

Your screenprint and your generated SQL statement shows that your current view is FIRST sorted by `node_created_order`. Though from your question it seems that you want it to be sorted by "start date of the event".

So just delete the first field in your list of SORT CRITERIA and see what happens next ...

Comment: yes now it is working fine only one issue still that the correct sorting event is coming in admin but in frontend it is showing as latest entry how i will correct in front end

Comment: OK, that sounds like progress. I'm not sure i correctly understand your comment, but maybe it's just the ascending/descending order you need to change? If not can you better explain what your remaining issue is?

Comment: I mean that when i add filter in admin section the order is correct which i want but in front-end event order is not correct i cleared the cache also

Comment: I don't have an explanation for your lat comment. but why did you add a **fitler** now, even though your original question was about the **sort criteria**? Could it be that your first question (to get the sorting right) is solved but now you have like a new question related to adding that filter?